# Json_encode Array Multidimensional

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array which is a combination of string and int value
like this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 2,2 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 2,59 ) )
```

I need to make this array become like this

```
[['2',   2],['2',       59]]
```

I using json_encode but it return

```
[["2,2"],["2,59"]]
```

I'm using this array for chart

I read from http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php but no one from json_ecode list can return like that

can someone help me? thx

can you help me once again,

```
    $data = new stdClass(); 
    $data->name = 'SD';
    $data->data = $totalSD;
    $data2 = new stdClass(); 
    $data2->name = 'SMP';
    $data2->data = $totalSMP;
    $list = array();
    array_push($list, $data);
    array_push($list, $data2);
```

I Have array like this

```
$a =[{"name":"SD","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,2]},{"name":"SMP","data":[0,‌​0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];
```

I need to change the array to become like this

```
$a =[{name:'SD',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,2]},{name:'SMP',data:[0,0,0,0,0,‌​0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];
```

Comment: So you just want to explode the innerArrays by commas?

Comment: something like that, but the result will be [string,int]

Comment: I do not see any integers among the data of input array. Please, add var_export of your input data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is do-able, using `foreach()` loops and exploding the string on the `,` delimiter.

The below code uses the exact array you supplied above (based on the structure):

```
foreach($array as $key => &$item) {
    foreach($item as $k => $data) {
        $item = explode(',', $data[0]);
    }
}
```

Which returns:

```
[["2","2"],["2","59"]]
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/292845)

---

If you need the first `value` as a string and the second as an `int`, the following should suffice:

```
foreach($a as $key => &$item) {
    foreach($item as $k => $data) {
        list($string, $int) = explode(',', $data[0]);
        $item = array(strval($string), (int) $int);
    }
}
```

<sup>*It harnesses the use of [`strval()`](http://php.net/strval) to cast the first value as a string and we cast the second value as an int via the `(int)` loose-typing in PHP.*</sup>

Which returns:

```
[["2", 2],["2", 59]]
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/292850)

---

#### A Quick Note

I've used by-reference in the foreach to modify the original array. So basically, you'll fetch your data, run the foreach loops to modify it as you need and then you'll encode it. This is a pseudo example of how that process would go:

```
ARRAY = Get.ARRAY

FOREACH ( ARRAY AS KEY => &VAL) {
    FOREACH (VAL AS KEY => VALUE) {
        LIST(FIRST_ITEM, LAST_ITEM) = EXPLODE(',', VALUE);
        VALUE = ARRAY ( strval(FIRST_ITEM), (int) LAST_ITEM );
    }
}

ECHO json_encode(ARRAY);
```

Comment: what i want for the result is [['2',   2],['2',       59]]

Comment: can you help me once again, I Have array like this
$a =[{"name":"SD","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,2]},{"name":"SMP","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];

I need to change the array to become like this
$a =[{name:'SD',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,17,2]},{name:'SMP',data:[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}];